# How to force text to be displayed below the header?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

How can I avoid the document text and the header overlapping?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set margins to your document, in order to take into account the space used by the header. Have a look at this [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=17). In particular, you are interested by this [Document constructor](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html#Document%28com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29):

```
Document doc = new Document(Rectangle pageSize,
    float marginLeft,
    float marginRight,
    float marginTop,        // <-- you want to play with this paramater
    float marginBottom)
```

Comment: I just want to change the position of the content, paper size unchanged.

Comment: You will not change the paper size, just the margins. Actually, the only thing you need to do is modify the `marginTop` in order to make the text start a bit below than the default position.

Comment: So.How do I change the marginTop and marginBottom ?It is in a class inside?

Comment: As I said in my answer, use the indicated `Document` constructor.