# Table overlaps header when table split into multiple pages

Tags: itext

I am generating a pdf document using iText in java. The pdf has a header and a table. When the table continues to the next page, first row of the table overlaps into the header. How to display the remaining table rows below the header in the next page

Comment: possible duplicate of [Header overlap in itext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387728/header-overlap-in-itext)

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387728/header-overlap-in-itext and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223592/how-to-force-text-to-be-displayed-below-the-header and other questions. It's all a matter of defining the margins correctly.

Comment: I tried to set margin using doc.setMargins(30, 30, 50, 30), but header is also moving to down if I set the margin. see my below code for adding header image:

Comment: HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase( new Chunk(Image.getInstance("https://localhost/admin/img/logo.png"),0,-25)), false);
header.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
header.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
doc.setHeader(header);

Comment: You are using a very old version of iText. The `doc.setHeader()` method has been removed from iText 5 years ago. It is no longer supported. You need to upgrade. You will get no support whatsoever for the iText version you're using.

Comment: Itext 5 requires a paid license so we are using itext4.2.o as we doing POC

Comment: That's a lame excuse. As long as you don't start distributing your application (either physically or in a SaaS environment), you can use iText under the AGPL. Also: you're doing a POC using an old version that contains many bugs (instead of making a real POC with the best version available) after which you're going to have to rewrite everything once you decide to switch to iText 5. That's short-sighted.

Comment: Thanks Bruno Lowagie, actually our client asked to use itext 4.2.0 only ,so we went for it. Can't it be possible to solve this issue with itext 4.2.0?

Comment: There has never been an official release of iText with number 4.2.0. I know because I've been responsible for the release management for more than 10 years. This means that you obtained a version of iText from a third party site. That third party could have added no matter what: spyware? viruses? Please tell your customer that he should read http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq You for one should refuse to do assignments using unsupported versions of iText. As soon as anything goes wrong: you'll get all the blame (from your customer, from us, from every one). Don't take that risk!

Comment: I am using http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/4.2.0 maven dependency.

Comment: Somebody with the nickname weiyeh has put it there: https://github.com/weiyeh I have no idea who this is, but he's not affiliated with https://github.com/itext

Comment: I think that you are working for Nielsen. As far as I know, Nielsen doesn't like people to introduce obsolete software into their code base. Please inform your customer that you'll start using the most recent version of iText.

Comment: Please see this if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387728/header-overlap-in-itext/33167752#33167752